# DataGridComboBoxColumn Values from Custom Class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a CommentsData class and this is used to load, manipulate and save values in a DataGrid. I want to make the Status field in the class shown as a dropdown in the grid. The Comment values need to be populated one time only. I have tried many variations but this does not work. The combo is blank. I need to be able to populate the values in the combo and when the selection changes the value should remain there and not dissappear.

Here is the Xaml for the Grid (Updated 2)

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="grdComments" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" BeginningEdit="grdComments_BeginningEdit" InitializingNewItem="grdComments_InitializingNewItem" PreviewKeyDown="grdComments_PreviewKeyDown" SizeChanged="grdComments_SizeChanged">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Author}" Header="Author" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding UserValues}" DisplayMemberPath="UserStatus" SelectedValuePath="UserStatus" SelectedValue="{Binding Status, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Comment}" Header="Comment" Width="570" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Here is the code for the CommentData class (Updated 2)

```
public class CommentsData 
{

    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<StatusValue> UserValues { get; set; }

    public CommentsData()
    {
        UserValues = new ObservableCollection<StatusValue>();

        UserValues.Add(new StatusValue("New"));
        UserValues.Add(new StatusValue("Open"));
        UserValues.Add(new StatusValue("ReOpen"));
        UserValues.Add(new StatusValue("Closed"));

    }

}

public class StatusValue
{
    public string UserStatus { get; set; }

    public StatusValue (string value)
    {
        UserStatus = value;
    }
}
```

Here is the code where the comments list is initialized

```
private List<CommentsData> _commentsList;

private void InitializeObjects()
{
        _commentsList = new List<CommentsData>();
        grdComments.ItemsSource = _commentsList;

}
```

The above code is working Thanks to all the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on MSDN article about [DataGridComboBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx) to populate the drop-down list, you must first set the ItemsSource property for the ComboBox by using one of the following options:

- A static resource.
- An x:Static code entity.
- An inline collection of ComboBoxItem types.

If you want to bind `ComboBox.ItemsSource` to object property, it`s easier to use `DataGridTemplateColumn` like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserValues}" DisplayMemberPath="UserStatus" SelectedValuePath="UserStatus" SelectedValue="{Binding Status, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: The list is populating and the selection also persists, however when I try to fetch the data from the `DataGrid` to save it the value for status always remain New and does not reflect the changed value

Comment: @CodeMe, I forgot to add `UpdateSourceTrigger` to SelectedValue Binding. I\`m updating the code, should be working now.

Comment: does `UpdateSourceTrigger` require `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation?

Comment: @CodeMe, `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation is requred if you want to change property from code so that your GUI can detect and show the changes. If you just want to select the value from `ComboBox` and that\`s all, you can do it without this interface.

Comment: Your solution works for me, and I have also removed the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation as I do not require it. I will update the code again later. Any idea how to move the `ObservableCollection` to another class and the bind to it?like it is in the current code

Comment: @CodeMe, Rachel wrote about that. You can use RelativeSource binding to access this collection in DataContext of a DataGrid itself. Refer to her answer for code example.

Comment: Yes I have tried her Example but it is not working, the combo is coming empty.

Comment: @CodeMe, then you should specify how you set `DataGrid.ItemsSource`. This approach will only work if the class with UserValues is DataGrid\`s DataContext.

Comment: @rachel I have updated the post with what is working for me. Its a lillte inefficient but the orignal problem is solved. The Combo is populatin and the values do not dissapear when some item is selected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that I see missing from your code

First off, your class doesn't implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). That means, if a property changes on `CommentData`, it doesn't tell the UI that is has changed, so the UI doesn't update to display the new value.

Second, you are telling your `ComboBox` that there is a property called `Status` on each item, and use it as the `ComboBoxItem.Value`, however this property does not exist on `StatusValue`. Change it to refer to `UserStatus`, which is a valid property on `StatusValue`.

```
SelectedValuePath="UserStatus"
```

And last of all, you really shouldn't be re-creating the ComboBox items on each item. Instead, create the collection somewhere further up in the ViewModel hierarchy, or make it a static resource.

For example, if the class which contains your collection of `CommentsData` also contained your collection of `StatusValues`, you could use a `RelativeSource` binding to bind to it like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
    Path=DataContext.UserValues}"
```

Comment: as per @Rachel suggestion `INotifyPropertyChanged` has been implemented, `SelectedValuePath` also updated and the collection has been moved to where the list of comments are maintained. Now the combo list is coming empty I have updated the code so you can take a look.

Comment: @CodeMe I don't see your `DataGrid.ItemsSource` bound to `CommentList`. What's the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid`? It should be whatever class contains both the `CommentList` and the `UserValues` list, however if that's the case when I would see `ItemsSource="{Binding CommentList}"` on the DataGrid

Comment: sorry forgot to mention it, I have updated the code its this  `grdComments.ItemsSource = _commentsList;`. The class which contains both collections is my window class

Comment: @CodeMe Is your DataGrid's `DataContext` equal to the class which contains your `CommentList` and `UserValues`? If not, the RelativeSource binding will not work. You can tell if the DataContext is correct or not by binding the DataGrid's ItemsSource property to the CommentList in the XAML (`ItemsSource="{Binding _commentsList}"`. If the DataContext is not that class, you can always set it by using `grdComments.DataContext = this;` in the code behind

Comment: The `DataContext` thing is not working for me, but since the orignal problem is solved I will repost it for moving the collection to the window class

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would use instead your DataGridComboboxColumn:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserValues}" SelectedItem="{Binding Status}" DisplayMemberPath="UserStatus" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Also `CommentsData.Status` should be of type `StatusValue`, not `string`, so that you can bind the `SelectedItem` on it.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to have `CommentsData.Status` be a string. I usually recommend people use `SelectedValue` to bind the selected item instead of `SelectedItem`, because `SelectedItem` is by reference, which means if it doesn't point to the exact same reference in memory as the version in the ItemsSource, it won't get selected.

Comment: I recommended using `CommentsData.Status` of type `StatusValue` exactly because of `SelectedItem`. I personally recommend using `SelectedItem` so the selected item **is** one of the items of the list that is binded to the item source, especially when using MVVM pattern (you want the Selected Item instance to have the same reference as the item from the data source).

Comment: I suppose everyone has their own preference. I usually make one database call to get a list of ComboBox values, and then a 2nd database call to get records. If binding `SelectedItem`, I'd have to be sure the 2nd database call to get records attaches the ComboBox item obtained from the 1st database call, and doesn't create or load it's own copy from the database. This is particularly an issue with ORM systems such as Entity Framework, which automatically creates related items.

Comment: When I make `CommentsData.Status` to be of type  `StatusValue` then it is not showing the selected item, this is probably because of the above things which you have discussed but what should I do now?

Comment: If `CommentsData.Status` is of type `StatusValue`, then you'll have to use `SelectedItem` for binding, not `SelectedValue`. See the code above for the correct bindings. I've tested the code above and it's working for me.